# Complete action using dialog pops up twice when accessing a Location link from web browser

Tags: android, browser, android-intent, web

**[Steps to reproduce]:**

1. Create a an Activity
2. Insert a url to open in browser
3. Now there is further a link in that web page that we have opened.
4. Open the Location link in the web page, and then Complete action using dialog will pop up
5. Select Browser from Complete action using dialog

**[Actually Result]:**

5. The Complete action using dialog pops up again after step5.

**[Expectedly Result]:**

5. The given link in web page should be launched in browser.

**[Reproduce Rate]:**

Attempts: 10 times. Failed: 10 times.

Please let me know where can be problem browser, Server or my Activity App? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I am also having this problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Tiago were you able to find solution for this?